# Error connecting ESX 5.0.0 to domain

Tags: active-directory, security, vmware-esxi

I am trying to connect an ESX 5.0.0 to our Domain Controler, in order to give a Domain group specific roles security. But I do not see any groups after the host connects to the domain.

Under Configuration -> Authentication Services - I connected the host to the domain:
[image]

I created the role I wanted, with the selected approved features
[image]

But when I want to add a permission to a set of VM's, I can not see "my domain" on the drop down, only the: "localhost"
[image]

- How do I see "my domain" on the Domain drop down - so I can select the domain group to give the role to?

I want to point out that I followed the [instructions to connect to the domain](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1023189) form VMware site on how to (just taking the part of creating a role and adding permissions)

Comment: Where is the vCenter installed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the ESX host's domain account isn't disabled.  If that's OK, try dropping the ESXi host from the domain, deleting it's computer object in the domain and add it back.

Failing that, try  updating your host to 5.1 or later.  Version 5.1 is working perfectly for us, I don't have a 5.0 host to check.